# Play video with alpha channel in Android?

Tags: android, video, alpha

Is it possible to play a video with alpha channel in you Android app? I'll need to use minimum version as 2.2. I can't use setAlpha method due to this.

Can anyone tell me alternate solution which works for 2.2+ Version ?

Thanks in advance